# setuptools verify file modified

Tags: python, caching, setuptools

I want to add a `build` command with extended functionality.  Specifically, it compiles a Go shared library.  It is a long process, and the Go source is rarely modified. Hence...

## The Question

Is there any way to ask `setuptools` to remember the last modified date of the file(s) at the time it was run, or will I need a more serious build tool (like SCons).  I don't care if it identifies the recency by timestamping or any other simplistic strategy.

---

Below is the code in question:

```
class BuildGo(build_py):
    '''
    Build Go bindings before building Python extension
    '''

    def run(self):
        # What should go into go_sources_modified?
        if self.go_sources_modified():
            self.compile_go()
        build_py.run(self)

    def compile_go(self):
        version = None
        refusal = 'Will not compile Go bindings'
        try:
            version = subprocess.check_output(['go', 'version'])
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            print('Didn\'t find Go compiler.')
            print(refusal)
            return
        match = re.search(br'go(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)', version)
        if match:
            version = tuple(map(int, match.group(1, 2, 3)))
        else:
            print('Unrecognized version of Go compiler: {}'.format(version))
            print(refusal)
            return
        req_version = 1, 9, 1
        if version < req_version:
            print('You need Go compiler version higher than: {}'.format(
                req_version,
            ))
            print(refusal)
            return
        try:
            result = subprocess.check_output([
                'go',
                'build',
                '-v',
                '-buildmode=c-shared',
                '-o',
                SHLIB_LOCATION,
                SHLIB_PACKAGE,
            ])
            print(result)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print(e.stderr)
            raise
```

Comment: No, there is no way. You have to implement something yourself.

Comment: @phd well, negative result is a result. You can post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use functions from `distutils.dep_util` module to check if any of the go sources have been modified since you have last built the library:

```
from distutils.dep_util import newer_group

class BuildGo(build_py):
    ...

    def go_sources_modified(self):
        gosrc = pathlib.Path('go/src/lib')
        go_sources = list(str(f.resolve()) for f in gosrc.rglob('*.go'))
        golib = 'go/pkg/mylib.a'
        return newer_group(go_sources, golib)
```

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed work, and covers all my needs. This is just a note of caution for others: this is not a 100% correct solution, since Go sources aren't necessarily covered by `*.go` (for example, you could have `*.s` assembly sources) pattern on one hand, and not all `*.go` files constitute package sources. (for example you could have tests `*_test.go`). A more exact version would've been something like: `go list -f '{{.CgoFiles}}' $package` + the same for `GoFiles`, plus the same for all imported packages etc.

Comment: @wvxvw Yeah, unfortunately I'm no expert in Go. If you have an idea how to call this function from python code and process the file list, feel free to improve my answer!